# No se crean las claves foráneas en tabla pivote

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 2 tablas, una tabla juegos y otra tabla usuarios. La relación en N:N con lo que necesito una tabla para pivotar. El caso es que en la tabla pivote "apuestas" no se crean las claves foráneas. Estoy trabajando en local, con wamp, normalmente al crear una clave foránea, se establece un link en las tuplas dentro de la columna de la FK y no me lo está creando. Sí que aparece una llave (plateada) indicando que esa columna es un índice.

Dejo las tablas por si alguien me puede echar un cable:

```
/*TABLA JUEGOS*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `juegos`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `juegos` (
  `id` int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_subcategoria` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `imagen` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (id_subcategoria)
  REFERENCES subcategoria(id)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_spanish_ci;
```

---

```
/*TABLA USUARIOS*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `usuarios`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `fecha_ingreso` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `acumulado` int(11) DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;
```

---

```
/*LA TABLA PIVOTE = APUESTAS*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `apuestas`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `apuestas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_juego` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `apostado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_apuesta` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  FOREIGN KEY (id_juego) references juegos (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) references usuarios (id)

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_spanish_ci;
```

Los campos tienen el mismo tipo, no entiendo porqué no me crea esos "links" cuando en el resto de tablas sí que me lo crea.
El error que me muestra es:

> 1215 - No puede adicionar clave extranjera constraint (y hace referencia a la tabla usuarios).

Si ejecuto:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `apuestas`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `apuestas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_juego` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `apostado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_apuesta` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  FOREIGN KEY (id_juego) references juegos (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_spanish_ci;
```

todo funciona bien, y en la pestaña insertar (de phpmyadmin) me muestra un "combo box" con las opciones que puedo seleccionar en el campo id_juego.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que el problema que tenés es que `Usuarios` es una tabla definida como `MyIsam` en lugar de `Innodb`, y a no ser que haya cambiado `MyIsam` no soporta claves foráneas.

Tendrías que convertir la tabla `Usuarios` a `Innodb`.

Comment: Eso era! muchas gracias